# Is there an Ubuntu One files iPhone client?

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, iphone

Is it possible to access files in my account Ubuntu One via iPhone?

Answer (score 8):

An iPhone client is on our roadmap, so you will eventually be able to. I can't quite tell you when it will be launched, so keep an eye out on our blog for when we announce it.

Comment: A notes sync app for iOS would also be great.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile two Ubuntu One client apps have been released in the App Store: **Ubuntu One Files** and **Ubuntu One Music**. And most recently, there has appeared an free app called **webNotes** which syncs notes with Tomboy using your Ubuntu One account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There is a files app, and a music streaming app. You can read more about them, and find the links to download them, here: https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/iphone/

Answer (score -2):

I´ve asked this to the Ubuntu-One team,and get the same aswer. While the app for files is released I´m using Dropbox; you can visualize your photos, read pdf, and get a link to share the file with someone else.